# Refactor help needed - method with to many parameters

Tags: java, methods, parameters, refactoring

I found some brilliant code with over 30 parameters given to a method  (I lost the count).
The implementation contains more than 500 lines with *if/then/else* and *switch* block's.

How could this be refactored in a clean way?
What would your advise be on this?

A lot of implementations are all over the application and all push these parameters.

Problem method:

```
public static User findUser (
    String userCode, String lastName, String firstName,
    String alternativeLastName, String sex, int day, int month, int year,
    String locationParameter, String locationInfo,
    Id groupId, Id organizationId, Id orderId,
    Id orderGroupId, Id orderOrganizationId,
    List<Id> groupIds, List<Id> organizationIds,
    List<Id> orderIds, List<Id> orderGroupIds,
    List<Id> orderOrganizationIds,
    String timeRange, Long daysAgo,
    Date dateFrom, Date dateUntil,
    CodingMap codingMap, List<String> languageList, String visitType,
    Account account, List<Group> accountGroups,
    Organization accountOrganization, Profile profile,
    AccessProfile accessProfile, Locale locale, int maxResults,
    long newTimeRange, long minimumTimeRange,
    boolean hideUserWithoutName, boolean withOrderInfo, boolean withVisitInfo,
    boolean orderEntryAvailable, 
    boolean hideDiscontinuedResults, boolean checkPatientAccessRights, boolean searchForCopies,
    boolean inOrderEntry, boolean allPatientCodes,
    boolean addPatientCharacteristics, boolean showSpeciesColumn,
    boolean patientDefinedWithPrivacyLevel,
    boolean excludePatientsWithoutCodeInSelectedCodingSystem
    ) throws CompanyException {
...
}
```

Used all over the place like this:

```
User.findUser(member.getCode(), context.lastName, context.firstName,
    context.alternativeLastName, context.sex,
    context.birthDate.getDay(), context.birthDate.getMonth(), 
    context.birthDate.getYear(),
    context.locationParameter, context.locationInfo,
    null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
    session.timeRange(), session.daysAgo(), session.dateFrom(),
    session.dateUntil(),
    order.codingMap(), order.languageList(), member.visitType(),
    null, null, null, null, null, locale, 25, 1000L,200L,
    session.point.booleanValue(), session.infobooleanValue(), false,
    true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false);
```

Comment: My advice would be to **RUN**.

Comment: refactoring? I'd call it 'rewriting' the code :D

Comment: 49 parameters in fact !! Why would you have to know everything about a user (including his shoes size...) to find him in a db or any other persistent unit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, I'd examine its actual usage a little further.

If you find that it is repeatedly called with specific subsets of these parameters, you might be able to do something like:

```
User.FindUserByABC(A, B, C)
User.FindUserByXYZ(X, Y, Z)
```

If this is not suitable, as others have suggested I would create a `SearchParams` class. All properties would be initialised to default values and its usage would only involve setting the relevant search terms required for each call, e.g.:

```
SearchParams params = new SearchParams(){A = "...", Z = "..."}
User.FindUser(params)
```

The latter would certainly clean up the calling code at least, with minimal impact to the existing underlying mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `Predicate` interface (or use [guava's](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html)):

```
interface Predicate<T> { boolean apply(T input); }
```

and change your method to:

```
User findUser(Predicate<User> p) {
    //find user
}
```

You then call it like this:

```
findUser(new Predicate<User> () {
    public boolean apply(User user) {
        return member.getCode().equals(user.getCode())
               && user.lastname.equals(context.lastname); //etc.
    }
});
```

Next step could be to introduce a UserQuery using a fluent syntax to easily create those queries. It would then look like:

```
UserQuery query = new UserQuery();
query.lastname(context.lastname)
       .code(member.getCode()); //etc
Predicate<User> p = query.build();
User user = findUser(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a *method class* with a *builder* for all necessary parameters:

```
public class FindUser {
    // fields that represent necessary parameters
    private final String lastName;
    ...

    // fields that represent optional parameters
    private Id groupId;
    ...

    // builder class for necessary parameters
    public static class Builder {
        private String lastName;
        ...

        public Builder lastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            return this;
        }
        ...

        public FindUser build {
            return new FindUser(this);
        }
    }

    // constructor taking a builder with all necessary parameters
    private FindUser(Builder builder){
        // check here, whether all fields are really set in the builder
        this.lastName = builder.lastName;
        ...
    }

    // setters for all optional parameters
    public FindUser groupId(Id groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
        return this;
    }
    ...

    // the action
    public User compute() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Copy the former method body inside the new compute method of the method class. Afterwards you can refactor this method by extracting many chunks of code into their own methods and maybe classes.

The last two steps:

1) Inside the old findUser method, create a new object of the method class and call the compute method. That will not reduce the size of the parameter list.

2) Change all usages of the findUser method to use the new method class, then delete the old findUser method.

Usage will be:

```
FindUser fu = new FindUser.Builder()
        .lastname("last name")
        ...
        .build()
        .groupId(new GroupId())
        ...;
User user = fu.compute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate all these parameters in a class

```
class MethodParam {
        String userCode; String lastName; String firstName;
        String alternativeLastName; String sex; int day; int month; int year;
        String locationParameter; String locationInfo;
        Id groupId; Id organizationId; Id orderId;
        Id orderGroupId; Id orderOrganizationId;
        List<Id> groupIds; List<Id> organizationIds;
        List<Id> orderIds; List<Id> orderGroupIds;
        List<Id> orderOrganizationIds;
        String timeRange; Long daysAgo;
        Date dateFrom; Date dateUntil;
        CodingMap codingMap; List<String> languageList; String visitType;
        Account account; List<Group> accountGroups;
        Organization accountOrganization; Profile profile;
        AccessProfile accessProfile; Locale locale; int maxResults;
        long newTimeRange; long minimumTimeRange;
        boolean hideUserWithoutName; boolean withOrderInfo; boolean withVisitInfo;
        boolean orderEntryAvailable; 
        boolean hideDiscontinuedResults; boolean checkPatientAccessRights; boolean searchForCopies;
        boolean inOrderEntry; boolean allPatientCodes;
        boolean addPatientCharacteristics; boolean showSpeciesColumn;
        boolean patientDefinedWithPrivacyLevel;
        boolean excludePatientsWithoutCodeInSelectedCodingSystem;
}
```

and then send that class to the method

```
findUser(MethodParam param) {
  ....
}
```

OR

put all the params in the map with a well defined constants as the keys

```
Map<String,Object> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
paramMap.put(Constants.USER_CODE, userCode);
```

...

and accept the map as parameter

```
findUser(Map<String, Object> param) {
      ....
}
```

As far as the if/else, switch are concerned, they have to be divided into logical small sub methods to reduce the cyclometric complexity

Answer (score 1):

You'd better create an object with all these parameters as atributes and deal with it all over the code.

```
    public class MyObeject{
    String userCode, String lastName, String firstName,
    String alternativeLastName, String sex, int day, int month, int year,
    String locationParameter, String locationInfo,
    Id groupId, Id organizationId, Id orderId,
    Id orderGroupId, Id orderOrganizationId,
    List<Id> groupIds, List<Id> organizationIds,
    List<Id> orderIds, List<Id> orderGroupIds,
    List<Id> orderOrganizationIds,
    String timeRange, Long daysAgo,
    Date dateFrom, Date dateUntil,
    CodingMap codingMap, List<String> languageList, String visitType,
    Account account, List<Group> accountGroups,
    Organization accountOrganization, Profile profile,
    AccessProfile accessProfile, Locale locale, int maxResults,
    long newTimeRange, long minimumTimeRange,
    boolean hideUserWithoutName, boolean withOrderInfo, boolean withVisitInfo,
    boolean orderEntryAvailable, 
    boolean hideDiscontinuedResults, boolean checkPatientAccessRights, boolean searchForCopies,
    boolean inOrderEntry, boolean allPatientCodes,
    boolean addPatientCharacteristics, boolean showSpeciesColumn,
    boolean patientDefinedWithPrivacyLevel,
    boolean excludePatientsWithoutCodeInSelectedCodingSystem
}

findUser(MyObject obj);
```

And fill only the attributes you need in each case. I guess some of them will be optional in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace this with a small sql database with a simple primary key for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Make builder with self-explaining setters? I understand that 30 setters is not much better, but you can at least generate them programmatically. And is it really that many *necessary* parameters?